# Loss and accuracy not changing of LSTM model

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, pytorch, lstm

[Picture of the train and test loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YvoV.png)Here’s a look at the LSTM model
`

```
# Create LSTM Model
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, output_dim):
    super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
    # Number of hidden dimensions
    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim

    # Number of hidden layers
    self.layer_dim = layer_dim

    # LSTM
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, batch_first=True, dropout=0.1)

    # Readout layer       
    self.f1 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    self.dropout_layer = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
    self.softmax = nn.Softmax()
    def forward(self, x):
    # Initialize hidden state with zeros

       h0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.layer_dim, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim).type(torch.FloatTensor))

    # Initialize cell state

       c0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.layer_dim, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim).type(torch.FloatTensor))

    # One time step
       out, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x, (h0,c0))
       out = self.dropout_layer(hn[-1])
       out = self.f1(out)
       out = self.softmax(out)    
       return out

    #LSTM Configuration
batch_size = 3000
num_epochs = 20
learning_rate = 0.001#Check this learning rate

# Create LSTM
input_dim = 1       # input dimension
hidden_dim = 30     # hidden layer dimension
layer_dim = 15  # number of hidden layers
output_dim = 1      # output dimension
num_layers = 10      #num_layers

print("input_dim = ", input_dim,"\nhidden_dim = ", hidden_dim,"\nlayer_dim = ", layer_dim,"\noutput_dim = ", output_dim)


model = LSTMModel(input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, output_dim)
model.cuda()
error = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)


graph_index = 0
test_loss = []
train_loss = []
plt_test_index = []
plt_train_index = []
tmp_index = []
tmp_train = []
tmp_test = []


# model.init_hidden()

for epoch in range(num_epochs):

  # Train
  model.train()
  loss_list_train = []
  loss_list_test = []

  total_train = 0
  equals_train = 0
  total_test = 0
  num0_train = 0
  num1_train = 0
  num0_test = 0
  num1_test = 0
  equals_test = 0
  TP_train = 0
  FP_train = 0
  TN_train = 0
  FN_train = 0
  TP_test = 0
  FP_test = 0
  TN_test = 0
  FN_test = 0

#   for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(train_loader):
  for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(train_loader):
    train  = Variable(inputs.type(torch.FloatTensor).cuda())
    targets = Variable(targets.type(torch.FloatTensor).cuda())
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(train)
    loss = error(outputs, targets)
    loss_list_train.append(loss.item())
    loss.backward()
    # loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    optimizer.step()
    t = np.where(targets.cpu().detach().numpy() > 0.5, 1, 0)
    o = np.where(outputs.cpu().detach().numpy() > 0.5, 1, 0) 
    total_train += t.shape[0]
    equals_train += np.sum(t == o)
    num0_train += np.sum(t == 0)
    num1_train += np.sum(t == 1)
    TP_train += np.sum(np.logical_and(t == 1, o==1))
    FP_train += np.sum(np.logical_and(t == 1, o==0))
    TN_train += np.sum(np.logical_and(t == 0, o==0))
    FN_train += np.sum(np.logical_and(t == 0, o==1))      
    tb.save_value('Train Loss', 'train_loss', globaliter, loss.item())
    globaliter += 1
    tb.flush_line('train_loss')
    print(i)

  # Test
  model.eval()
  targets_plot = np.array([])
  outputs_plot = np.array([])
  inputs_plot = np.array([])


  for inputs, targets in test_loader:

    inputs = Variable(inputs.type(torch.FloatTensor).cuda())
    targets = Variable(targets.type(torch.FloatTensor).cuda())  
    outputs = model(inputs)
    loss = error(outputs, targets)
    loss_list_test.append(loss.item())
    #print(outputs.cpu().detach().numpy())
    t = np.where(targets.cpu().detach().numpy() > 0.5, 1, 0)
    o = np.where(outputs.cpu().detach().numpy() > 0.5, 1, 0)
    total_test += t.shape[0]
    equals_test += np.sum(t == o)
    num0_test += np.sum(t == 0)
    num1_test += np.sum(t == 1)
    TP_test += np.sum(np.logical_and(t == 1, o==1))
    FP_test += np.sum(np.logical_and(t == 0, o==1))
    TN_test += np.sum(np.logical_and(t == 0, o==0))
    FN_test += np.sum(np.logical_and(t == 1, o==0))
    tb.save_value('Test Loss', 'test_loss', globaliter2, loss.item())
    globaliter2 += 1
    tb.flush_line('test_loss')


  # Save value in array    
  graph_index += 1 
  plt_train_index.append(graph_index)
  plt_test_index.append(graph_index)
  train_loss.append(np.mean(np.array(loss_list_train)))
  test_loss.append(np.mean(np.array(loss_list_test)))

  print("------------------------------")
  print("Epoch : ", epoch)
  print("----- Train -----")
  print("Total =", total_train, " | Num 0 =", num0_train, " | Num 1 =", num1_train)
  print("Equals =", equals_train)
  print("Accuracy =", (equals_train / total_train)*100, "%")
  # print("TP =", TP_train / total_train, "% | TN =", TN_train / total_train, "% | FP =", FP_train / total_train, "% | FN =", FN_train / total_train, "%")
  print("----- Test -----")
  print("Total =", total_test, " | Num 0 =", num0_test, " | Num 1 =", num1_test)
  print("Equals =", equals_test)
  print("Accuracy =", (equals_test / total_test)*100, "%")
```

I am using the model to do binary classification on the sequence length of 300. The accuracy and the loss are not changing over several epochs.I tried changing the no. of layers,no of hidden states, activation function, but all to no avail. I don’t know what i am doing wrong, I am probably missing something fundamental. Any help is appreciated

Comment: what is the data you are training on? try overfitting your model on 2 samples, one that always classifies as 1, another as 0. Try replacing LSTM with linear layer. The idea is to simplify your model until it trains and works.

Comment: @Devstr the dataset is an ECG dataset,I am taking data(which is bigger than class 1 data sometimes) leading up to class 1 data as a part of the class 1 data and then performing the shifting action to create sequences of 300 and labeling this as class 1. Is this why the model is not learning because there is so much class 0 data as a part of class1?